# Is Qiskit's Estimator Primitive running PauliStrings in Parallel?

Tags: qiskit, vqe, qiskit-runtime

I am trying to run the following code:

```python
import numpy as np
from qiskit import *
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import Options   
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import QiskitRuntimeService, Estimator
from qiskit.algorithms.optimizers import NFT
from qiskit.circuit.library import TwoLocal
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp
from qiskit.algorithms.minimum_eigensolvers import VQE
from qiskit.opflow import X, Y, Z, I  
from qiskit.opflow import PauliSumOp


service = QiskitRuntimeService(token="YOUR-TOKEN",channel="ibm_quantum")
 
options = Options()
options.optimization_level=3 
options.execution.shots=100

#backend = service.backend("ibm_lagos")
backend = service.backend("ibmq_qasm_simulator")
estimator = Estimator(session=backend,options=options) 


hamiltonian_0= SparsePauliOp(['IIII'] ) 

hamiltonian_1=PauliSumOp(SparsePauliOp(['IIII', 'IIIZ', 'IIZI', 'IIZZ', 'IZII', 'IZIZ', 
'IZZI', 'IZZZ', 'ZIII', 'ZIIZ', 'ZIZI', 'ZIZZ', 'ZZII', 'ZZIZ', 'ZZZI', 'ZZZZ'],
              coeffs=[ 1.+0.j,  1.+0.j, 1.+0.j, 1.+0.j,  1.+0.j, 1.+0.j,
  1.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  1.+0.j,  1.+0.j,
  1.+0.j,  1.+0.j, 1.+0.j,  1.+0.j]), coeff=1.0)


dim=hamiltonian_0.num_qubits
ansatz = TwoLocal(dim, rotation_blocks=["ry"],entanglement='reverse_linear',entanglement_blocks="cx", reps=1)
optimizer = NFT(maxiter=100)


vqe = VQE(estimator=estimator, ansatz=ansatz, optimizer=optimizer )
result = vqe.compute_minimum_eigenvalue(hamiltonian_0)
```

In this code I want to compare the time it takes to compute the eigenvalue for the two Hamiltonians.

If I understand correctly, the VQE algorithm calculates a circuit for each of the PauliStrings, then sums the different expectation values and finally changes the parameters and repeats the whole process. So for the `hamiltonian_0` $(H_0=I\otimes I\otimes I \otimes I )$ the VQE shall make $1\times 100$ calculations and for `hamiltonian_1` that has 16 Paulistrings $(H_1=\sum_{i=0}^{15} P_i )$ , the VQE shall make $16\times 100$ calculations.

Whenever I run it , the `optimizer_time` of the VQEResult is the same for both `hamiltonian_0` and `hamiltonian_1` , roughly $1000~s$ .I would expect (maybe naively) , for the `hamiltonian_0` to be 16 times faster than `hamiltonian_1` .

I have also made several tests with similar, up to 8 qubit Hamiltonians using the primitives, but with `qasm_simulator`. I get the same `optimizer_time` for Hamiltonians with $1$ term and with $2^8$ terms.

Does anyone know why this happens? Is it because the estimator primitive has a parallelization procedure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Runtime Estimator you used groups Paulis into [commuting groups](https://qiskit.org/documentation/stubs/qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp.html#qiskit.quantum_info.SparsePauliOp.group_commuting) that can be measured simultaneously which is why you are seeing that result since the operator you have the paulis will group together. The [Estimator from Aer](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/aer/stubs/qiskit_aer.primitives.Estimator.html) has an `abelian_grouping` parameter where for local simulation that grouping can be disabled, but the Runtime has no such option since if you can measure them simultaneously it's more performant to do so.

I will observe that `maxiter` on the optimizer just limits how many iterations it can do. If it finds a minimum before that, according to its tolerances etc. it will stop, but the result will say how many iterations it did so you can factor that into account if needed.

Comment: Thank you very much ! To be honest , I do not know how to set the tolerances in NFT, unlike the SLSQP that is straightforward.